# Drivers Employment Contract for ThirdWorld Nationals

Tags: visa, germany, working-visas, contracts

it’s my pleasure to say hello to you all. Well after failing to lunch a complaint in the Administrative court of Belin due to the lack of enough funds and time. I came up with a conclusion to re—apply again at the embassy.

My employer intends to send me a new contract but has asked me if there are  any adjustments that need to be included or added in the contract in order to speed up or stand a chance to be granted a Germany visa. Your opinion please?????

It should be noted that I applied for a national visa before and I was rejected, the following were the reasons for rejection from the Embassy-;

“””The application was therefore to be decided at discretion. You are aiming to start working as a parcel delivery service in Germany. According to Section 2, Paragraph 2, 2nd Var. AufenthG in conjunction with Section 7 of Book Four of the Social Code to be employed as an employee, as you are to be employed dependently (according to the present employment contract
of March 26, 2020). The activity is also aimed at making a profit, or a remuneration (ie also pecuniary benefits) is agreed or customary for this. According to Section 18 of
the Residence Act, a foreigner can be granted a residence permit to work if the Federal Employment Agency has given its approval in accordance with Section 39 of the Residence Act or a statutory ordinance pursuant to Section 42 of the Residence Act or an intergovernmental agreement stipulates that employment is permitted without the consent of the Federal Employment Agency. According to Section 82,
Paragraph 1 of the Residence Act, you are required to immediately assert your concerns and the circumstances that are favorable to you, unless they are obvious or known, stating verifiable circumstances and the necessary evidence of your personal circumstances, other required certificates and permits as well to provide any other necessary evidence that you can provide without delay. It was not possible to obtain the consent of the competent federal agency for labor, which is required in accordance with Section 18 in conjunction with Section 39 of the Residence Act, as the requirement of Section 39 subs. 2 No. 1 Residence Act is not fulfilled. A suitable offense according to the Employment Ordinance or the Residence Act is not evident considering your nationality and the desired activity. In your case, the approval of the responsible employment agency cannot be given according to § 24a BeschV( professional drivers). In particular, it cannot be assumed that your previous employment in your home country is equivalent. Professional drivers within the meaning of the Employment Ordinance are employees in transport logistics, road freight transport and commercial road passenger transport. The employee must have an EU or EEA driving license of classes C1, C1E, C, CE, DI, DIE, D or DE as well as the basic qualification or the accelerated basic qualification. When submitting your application, you stated that you have had your first class B driving license since November 2020. You previously worked in the security industry. According to your information and according to the employment contract you have submitted, you intend to take up work as a parcel delivery service using a small vehicle. Employment for which only a class B driving license and possibly a passenger transport license is required are not covered by the scope of § 24a Employment Ordinance. As an applicant, you have to make the purpose of your stay plausible and provide evidence of the prerequisites for consenting to take up gainful employment. In accordance with the principle of proportionality, your private interests in a stay for the purpose of taking up gainful employment must then be weighed against the public interest. The legislature does not see the exercise of the activity you are striving for by foreign employees in the public interest. A necessary fact in the BeschV is therefore not recorded. In the overall weighing of your private interests in a stay for the purpose of gainful employment against the public interest in a controlled and controlled entry of foreigners in the legally prescribed way, greater weight was attached to the public interest according to dutiful discretion. The embassy has this according to § 6 Abs. 3, 18 Abs. 3 AufenthG in conjunction with § 6 Abs. 2 Nr. 2 BeschV exercised discretion to your disadvantage. All in all, it therefore emerges that the public interest in a regulated entry of foreign workers, which is significantly affected by the circumstances already described, clearly outweighs your private interest in a stay in Germany. The application was therefore to be rejected. The refusal of the visa is upheld.
Advice on legal remedies: A suit can be brought against this decision at the Berlin Administrative Court within one month of its notification. Your private interest in a stay in Germany clearly outweighs it. The application was therefore to be rejected. The refusal of the visa is upheld. Advice on legal remedies: A suit can be brought against this decision at the Berlin
Administrative Court within one month of its notification. Your private interest in a stay in Germany clearly outweighs it. The application was therefore to be
rejected. The refusal of the visa is upheld””””

Do you think I can apply for some other visa type. I.e traineeship Kindly Advise!!!!

Gentlemen, what do you think the employer should add on my contract to to enable me get the visa this time around. I researched of the following “The new contract should oblige me to take part in measures for obtaining (accelerated) initial qualification and a German driving licence alongside employment at the company” what’s your opinion on this??

What are the chances for the Federal Employment Agency in Germany to approve my employment?

I do appreciate all efforts and help stay blessed! Kindly advise!

Peter.E

Comment: Sorry for the repeating somewhere on license types.

Comment: They seem to be saying that a) you don’t have the required licence to do the job; and b) foreign employees doing this type of (small) parcel delivery service is not deemed in the public interest. IMHO you’d be wasting your time and money reapplying.

Comment: "My employer intends to send me a new contract but has asked me if there are any adjustments that need to be included or added in the contract in order to speed up or stand a chance to be granted a Germany visa":  Who is this employer?  A legitimate employer in Germany who is sponsoring a foreign worker for a visa ought to know what conditions must be met for a successful visa application.  If they don't know, they ought to engage a German immigration lawyer.  That they are asking you about this is very odd.

Comment: This question has been asked before and a given comment there contains the answer: *This means you do not have the required EU Driver's Licence and no working contract that insures that employer will get you one. § 24a BeschV - Einzelnorm*

Comment: Guys I do appreciate your advise!